# How to set specified date bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [this bootstrap datepicker plugin](https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/) and I want to set class for my specified days for example I have booked days and I want to set a class for my these days but I don't want to disabed them how can I do hat ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#date-range12').dateRangePicker({
    inline: true,
    container: '#date-range12-container',
    alwaysOpen: true,
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    separator: ' to ',
    language: 'tr',
    showTopbar: false,
    showWeekNumbers: false,
    extraClass: 'date-range-picker19',
    monthSelect: true,
    yearSelect: true,
    customArrowPrevSymbol: '<a href="#" class="fa-blok fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></a>',
    customArrowNextSymbol: '<a href="#" class="fa-blok fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></a>',
    //maxDays: 7,
    //minDays: 3,
    startDate: moment(),
    startOfWeek: 'monday',
    customTopBar: 'Tarih Aralığı Seçiniz',
    showDateFilter: function(time, date) {
      return '<div style="padding:0 5px;">\
              <span style="font-weight:bold">' + date + '</span>\
              <div style="opacity:0.3;">$' + Math.round(Math.random() * 999) + '</div>\
              </div>';
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.date-picker {
    width: 170px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #303030;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2
}

.date-picker-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    //border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    background-color: #efefef;
    //padding: 5px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
    box-sizing: initial
}

.dp-clearfix {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0
}

.date-picker-wrapper.inline-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block
}

.date-picker-wrapper.single-date {
    width: auto
}

.date-picker-wrapper.no-shortcuts {
    //padding-bottom: 12px
}

.date-picker-wrapper.no-topbar {
    //padding-top: 12px
}

.date-picker-wrapper .footer {
    font-size: 11px;
    //padding-top: 3px
}

.date-picker-wrapper b {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 700
}

.date-picker-wrapper a {
    color: #6bb4d6;
    text-decoration: underline
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-name {
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.date-picker-wrapper .select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.date-picker-wrapper .select-wrapper:hover {
    text-decoration: underline
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-element {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.date-picker-wrapper .select-wrapper select {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-transform: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    opacity: .01
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    //border-radius: 3px;
    //background-color: #fff;
    background-color: #d0d5de;
    padding: 12px 12px 40px 12px;
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    _overflow: hidden;
    width:100% !important;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table {
    width: 190px;
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table.month2 {
    width: 190px;
    float: left
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table td,
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day {
    //padding: 5px 0;
    //line-height: 1;
    //font-size: 12px;
    //margin-bottom: 1px;
    //color: #ccc;
    //cursor: default;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ccc;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table div.day.lastMonth,
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table div.day.nextMonth {
    color: #999;
    cursor: default
}


.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .week-name {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.has-tooltip {
    cursor: help!important
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.has-tooltip .tooltip {
    white-space: nowrap
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time label {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.valid {
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #FFF;
}


.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.lastMonth,
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.nextMonth {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.real-today {
    background-color: #ffe684
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.real-today.checked,
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.real-today.hovering {
    background-color: #70ccd5
}

.date-picker-wrapper table .caption {
 height: 40px;
    background-color: #4d5567;
    color: #CBCDD0;
    padding: 13px 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.date-picker-wrapper table .caption>th:first-of-type,
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption>th:last-of-type {
    width: 27px;
}
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption .next,
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption .prev {
 width:50px;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display:block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#667493;
}
.caption .next{
 float:right;
}
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption .next:hover,
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption .prev:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    float: left;
    top: -5px;
    margin: 0 10px -10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    display:none;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-lines {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-line {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    position: relative
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-line .gap-1 {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid #fff;
    border-top: 8px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #eee
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-line .gap-2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #fff
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-line .gap-3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 8px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #fff
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-top-mask {
    width: 6px;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 1px;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 3
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-bottom-mask {
    width: 6px;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 7px;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 3
}

.date-picker-wrapper .selected-days {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar {
    line-height: 1.4;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 0
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .error-top,
.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .normal-top {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .default-top {
    display: block
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.error .default-top {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.error .error-top {
    display: block;
    color: red
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.normal .default-top {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.normal .normal-top {
    display: block
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.normal .normal-top .selection-top {
    color: #333
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .apply-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 6px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #d9eef7;
    border: solid 1px #0076a3;
    background: #0095cd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00adee, #0078a5);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00adee', endColorstr='#0078a5');
    color: #fff;
    line-height: initial
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .apply-btn.disabled {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #606060;
    border: solid 1px #b7b7b7;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ededed);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed')
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time {
    position: relative
}

.date-picker-wrapper.single-month .time {
    display: block
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time input[type=range] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time1 {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center
}

.time2 {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time1 {
    float: left
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time2 {
    float: right
}

.date-picker-wrapper .hour {
    text-align: right
}

.minute {
    text-align: right
}

.date-picker-wrapper .hide {
    display: none
}


.date-picker-wrapper .date-range-length-tip {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: none;
    background-color: #ff0;
    padding: 0 6px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
    -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
    -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3))
}

.date-picker-wrapper .date-range-length-tip:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #ff0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    bottom: -4px
}

.date-picker-wrapper.two-months.no-gap .month1 .next,
.date-picker-wrapper.two-months.no-gap .month2 .prev {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .week-number {
    padding: 5px 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    color: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
}
.day.toMonth.valid div[style="padding:0 5px;"]{
 padding:-1px !important;
}
.date-picker-wrapper .week-number.week-number-selected {
    color: #49e;
    font-weight: 700
}

.day.toMonth.valid div span,.day.toMonth.invalid div span {
    font-weight: normal !important;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.day.toMonth.valid div span+div {
 background: #4D5567;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    padding:7px 5px;
}
.day.toMonth.invalid div span{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    padding:7px 5px;
}
.week-name th:first-child{
 color:transparent !important;
}


.day.toMonth.valid:hover {
    background-color:#4499EE !important;
    color: #fff !important
}
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .checked {
    background-color: #9cdbf7 !important;
}
.date-picker-wrapper.date-range-picker19 .day.first-date-selected { background-color: #4499EE !important;color:#FFF !important; }
.date-picker-wrapper.date-range-picker19 .day.last-date-selected { background-color: #4499EE !important; color:#FFF !important;}
.fa-blok{
 display:inline;
 color:#FFF !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
 
   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.valid,.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.invalid{
     padding:8px;
   }
   .month1{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
   }
   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table{
    width:100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    float:none;
   }
   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table td, .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table th{
    font-size: 12px;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 490px) {
 
   .day.toMonth.valid div span, .day.toMonth.invalid div span{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
   }
   .day.toMonth.valid div span+div{
     padding:3px 2px;
   }
 .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper{
  padding:0;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 446px) {
 
   .day.toMonth.valid div span+div{
     padding:3px 0;
   }
   .day.toMonth.valid div span, .day.toMonth.invalid div span{
    font-size: 11px;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.valid, .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.invalid{
     padding:5px 5px;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .day.toMonth.valid div span, .day.toMonth.invalid div span{
   font-size: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 12px;
  }

   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.valid, .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.invalid{
     padding:2px 0;
   }
 .day.toMonth.valid div span+div{
  font-size: 11px;
 }
}
.reserved{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.reserved:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #551A62;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56%;
    top: -4px;
    transform: rotate(116deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    left: -43px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.16.1/daterangepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.16.1/jquery.daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="date-range12" size="40" value="">
<div id="date-range12-container" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/jigoparozu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `showDateFilter` method to identify the dates where you want to add custom `class`. Please see exaple below. Here dates that needs to be highlighted are in `highlightdates` array.

Please note that `showDateFilter` filter is executed to identify the content of each date cell in the calendar.

```js
 
var highlightdates = [moment('22.12.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), moment('24.01.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY')]

$(document).ready(function () {

               $('#date-range12').dateRangePicker(
                   {
                       inline: true,
                       container: '#date-range12-container',
                       alwaysOpen: true,
                       format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
                       separator: ' to ',
                       language: 'tr',
                       showTopbar: false,
                       showWeekNumbers: false,
                       extraClass: 'date-range-picker19',
                       monthSelect: true,
                       yearSelect: true,
                       customArrowPrevSymbol: '<a href="#" class="fa-blok fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></a>',
                       customArrowNextSymbol: '<a href="#" class="fa-blok fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></a>',
                       //maxDays: 7,
                       //minDays: 3,
                       startDate: moment(),
                       startOfWeek: 'monday',
                       customTopBar: 'Tarih Aralığı Seçiniz',
                       showDateFilter: function (time, date) {
                           var doHighlight = highlightdates.some(function(item) {
                               return (item.isSame(moment(time), 'day') && item.isSame(moment(time), 'month') && item.isSame(moment(time), 'year'))
                           })
                           return '<div ' + (doHighlight ? 'class="highlight"' : '') + ' style="padding:0 5px;">\
                     <span style="font-weight:bold">'+ date + '</span>\
                     <div style="opacity:0.3;">$'+ Math.round(Math.random() * 999) + '</div>\
                    </div>';
                       }

                   });
           });
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
.date-picker {
    width: 170px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #303030;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2
}

.date-picker-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    //border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    background-color: #efefef;
    //padding: 5px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
    box-sizing: initial
}

.dp-clearfix {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0
}

.date-picker-wrapper.inline-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block
}

.date-picker-wrapper.single-date {
    width: auto
}

.date-picker-wrapper.no-shortcuts {
    //padding-bottom: 12px
}

.date-picker-wrapper.no-topbar {
    //padding-top: 12px
}

.date-picker-wrapper .footer {
    font-size: 11px;
    //padding-top: 3px
}

.date-picker-wrapper b {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 700
}

.date-picker-wrapper a {
    color: #6bb4d6;
    text-decoration: underline
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-name {
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.date-picker-wrapper .select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.date-picker-wrapper .select-wrapper:hover {
    text-decoration: underline
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-element {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.date-picker-wrapper .select-wrapper select {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-transform: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    opacity: .01
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    //border-radius: 3px;
    //background-color: #fff;
    background-color: #d0d5de;
    padding: 12px 12px 40px 12px;
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    _overflow: hidden;
    width:100% !important;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table {
    width: 190px;
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table.month2 {
    width: 190px;
    float: left
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table td,
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day {
    //padding: 5px 0;
    //line-height: 1;
    //font-size: 12px;
    //margin-bottom: 1px;
    //color: #ccc;
    //cursor: default;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ccc;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table div.day.lastMonth,
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table div.day.nextMonth {
    color: #999;
    cursor: default
}


.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .week-name {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.has-tooltip {
    cursor: help!important
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.has-tooltip .tooltip {
    white-space: nowrap
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time label {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.valid {
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #FFF;
}


.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.lastMonth,
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.nextMonth {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.real-today {
    background-color: #ffe684
}

.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.real-today.checked,
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.real-today.hovering {
    background-color: #70ccd5
}

.date-picker-wrapper table .caption {
 height: 40px;
    background-color: #4d5567;
    color: #CBCDD0;
    padding: 13px 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.date-picker-wrapper table .caption>th:first-of-type,
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption>th:last-of-type {
    width: 27px;
}
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption .next,
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption .prev {
 width:50px;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display:block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#667493;
}
.caption .next{
 float:right;
}
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption .next:hover,
.date-picker-wrapper table .caption .prev:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    float: left;
    top: -5px;
    margin: 0 10px -10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    display:none;
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-lines {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-line {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    position: relative
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-line .gap-1 {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid #fff;
    border-top: 8px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #eee
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-line .gap-2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #fff
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-line .gap-3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 8px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #fff
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-top-mask {
    width: 6px;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 1px;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 3
}

.date-picker-wrapper .gap .gap-bottom-mask {
    width: 6px;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 7px;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 3
}

.date-picker-wrapper .selected-days {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar {
    line-height: 1.4;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 0
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .error-top,
.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .normal-top {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .default-top {
    display: block
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.error .default-top {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.error .error-top {
    display: block;
    color: red
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.normal .default-top {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.normal .normal-top {
    display: block
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar.normal .normal-top .selection-top {
    color: #333
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .apply-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 6px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #d9eef7;
    border: solid 1px #0076a3;
    background: #0095cd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00adee, #0078a5);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00adee', endColorstr='#0078a5');
    color: #fff;
    line-height: initial
}

.date-picker-wrapper .drp_top-bar .apply-btn.disabled {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #606060;
    border: solid 1px #b7b7b7;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ededed);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed')
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time {
    position: relative
}

.date-picker-wrapper.single-month .time {
    display: block
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time input[type=range] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time1 {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center
}

.time2 {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time1 {
    float: left
}

.date-picker-wrapper .time2 {
    float: right
}

.date-picker-wrapper .hour {
    text-align: right
}

.minute {
    text-align: right
}

.date-picker-wrapper .hide {
    display: none
}


.date-picker-wrapper .date-range-length-tip {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: none;
    background-color: #ff0;
    padding: 0 6px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
    -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
    -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3))
}

.date-picker-wrapper .date-range-length-tip:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #ff0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    bottom: -4px
}

.date-picker-wrapper.two-months.no-gap .month1 .next,
.date-picker-wrapper.two-months.no-gap .month2 .prev {
    display: none
}

.date-picker-wrapper .week-number {
    padding: 5px 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    color: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
}
.day.toMonth.valid div[style="padding:0 5px;"]{
 padding:-1px !important;
}
.date-picker-wrapper .week-number.week-number-selected {
    color: #49e;
    font-weight: 700
}

.day.toMonth.valid div span,.day.toMonth.invalid div span {
    font-weight: normal !important;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.day.toMonth.valid div span+div {
 background: #4D5567;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    padding:7px 5px;
}
.day.toMonth.invalid div span{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    padding:7px 5px;
}
.week-name th:first-child{
 color:transparent !important;
}


.day.toMonth.valid:hover {
    background-color:#4499EE !important;
    color: #fff !important
}
.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .checked {
    background-color: #9cdbf7 !important;
}
.date-picker-wrapper.date-range-picker19 .day.first-date-selected { background-color: #4499EE !important;color:#FFF !important; }
.date-picker-wrapper.date-range-picker19 .day.last-date-selected { background-color: #4499EE !important; color:#FFF !important;}
.fa-blok{
 display:inline;
 color:#FFF !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
 
   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.valid,.date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.invalid{
     padding:8px;
   }
   .month1{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
   }
   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table{
    width:100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    float:none;
   }
   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table td, .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table th{
    font-size: 12px;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 490px) {
 
   .day.toMonth.valid div span, .day.toMonth.invalid div span{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
   }
   .day.toMonth.valid div span+div{
     padding:3px 2px;
   }
 .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper{
  padding:0;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 446px) {
 
   .day.toMonth.valid div span+div{
     padding:3px 0;
   }
   .day.toMonth.valid div span, .day.toMonth.invalid div span{
    font-size: 11px;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.valid, .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.invalid{
     padding:5px 5px;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .day.toMonth.valid div span, .day.toMonth.invalid div span{
   font-size: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 12px;
  }

   .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.valid, .date-picker-wrapper .month-wrapper table .day.toMonth.invalid{
     padding:2px 0;
   }
 .day.toMonth.valid div span+div{
  font-size: 11px;
 }
}
.reserved{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.reserved:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #551A62;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56%;
    top: -4px;
    transform: rotate(116deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    left: -43px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>jQuery Date Range Picker Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.16.1/daterangepicker.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.16.1/jquery.daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
   <input type="hidden" id="date-range12" size="40" value="">
    <div id="date-range12-container" style="width:100%;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much so how can we  set a special date for example 22.12.2017 or 24.01.208 instead of 1 or 2 etc.etc is that possible ?

Comment: yes, just parse those dates using momentjs and add it to the array.

Comment: is there any example to that i gotta apply it on example?